# External Drupal site

Tags: php, html, drupal, content-management-system, drupal-7

How can I make the website layout standalone without including it into drupal?

I can do this with wordpress: e.g `index.php` (my layout), `/css/style.css` (my styling), `/wp/~` (wordpress directory)

Hope that gives an idea of what I'm trying to do.

Before you ask, I prefer external methods because I like to make a lot of experimental sites, usually CMS limit some of my concepts when the site is within the database.

Thanks.

Comment: there is also an index.php and an theme directory with the corrsponding files. but hwy do you want to do a standalone website (without mysql)? then you dont need an cms. and drupal is widely used (eg from the white huse) and you can change everything. what should be limited? you can use jquery, prototype ... what you want

Comment: I do want to use MySQL but only for content, [please correct me if I'm mistaken though:] I believe drupals html layouts/ pages are stored as MySQL data. Another option I guess would be to ask "How do I turn off everything visually for drupal and how can use my own html code out of drupals system" If that makes any sense.

Comment: Key to Drupal's architecture is the concept of overriding, which applies to content generation and display.  Drupal does maintain a theme registry in the DB that contains a list of appropriate functions and templates to call.  But those functions and templates are included in files, as in any other CMS.  You can create your own theme with template files and any function overrides you would like.  You could start by creating a sub-theme from a base theme such as Zen.  That way some of the heavy lifting is already done for you and you can focus more on the design.

Comment: they leyouts / templates are stored as files (.tpl)

Comment: Thanks @MEsch . Still after some consideration I still feel like external use is best suited for what I do as I sometimes create very experimental layouts that a cms's usually can't handel in a tidy fashion, the concept of over ride is what I'm trying to avoid.  I read up on drupal_bootstrap I think it may be what I'm looking for. Basically all I want is have a clean root and access the /drupal directory via php when needed.

Comment: @Daniel Ruf , Thanks though I still want to have drupal out of the root

Comment: meant layouts =) out of the root? create a directory and put drupal in it? i think we all dont understand what you exactly want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use Drupal as a storage/authentication engine, look at the Services module, or writing a custom module that provides handlers to take data from your standalone pages via AJAX or form submissions and process them in Drupal, then serve data back out to your standalone app.

To get data in: Post it via AJAX or a form submission that transparently redirects back to your standalone pages.

To get data out: Use direct MySQL queries, JSON requests or bootstrap Drupal so you can use the Drupal API inside your standalone pages.

Most of the time though you can do nearly anything "the Drupal way" once you understand how it does things (which is very quirky at times). Check out http://drupal.org/project/examples for demos of how certain things are implemented, and the http://drupal.org/project/clean base theme for a nice minimalist starter theme to work from.

Answer (score 0):

With the subtheme, You do in some sense create your own "external" css.
You can add custom css in the info config file, and use different template tpl.php to implement the css on various the pages. 
That is not all that different from write:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
```

Drupal just try to organize it for you.

Comment: It's not really the css I'm worried about it's the html layout & tags

Comment: download zen theme, and start creating your own theme / sub theme using css, html and javascript, you can change everything in the templates and also override every module template, in drupal a website is created by the page.tpl and some other templates and also drupal doesnt limit you nowhere. you just have to include your stuff into the templates and maybe you also want to create some own modules.

Comment: Understand and I'm sure I can make my own themes etc, that's not what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to use drupal externally I want to know if it's possible and how.

Comment: In your question "can do this with wordpress: e.g index.php (my layout), /css/style.css (my styling), /wp/~ (wordpress directory)" It can be accomplish in Drupal by modify theme external css. to change layout,tag; you either use the GUI provided by Drupal, or write your own template file, which won't be usable outside Drupal. CMS wrote tag for you, so you can focus on design, but I don't believe there is a standard among CMS for writing tags, hence sadly you cannot use the css that is written according to the tags in Drupal externally in wp for Example, and I doubt you can do that in reverse.